# vue - typescript typed class

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Im using vue25 and I would like to have a model **typed class**, so on my project I add a **.ts** file as

```js
export class League {

  id:number;
  title : string;
  country_name:string;
  type:string;
  used:Boolean;

  constructor(data) {
    
    if (data != null) {
      this.id = data.id;
      this.title = data.title;
      this.country_name = data.country_name;
      this.type = data.type;
      this.used = data.used;
    }
    else {
      this.id = 0;
      this.title = '';
      this.country_name = '';
      this.type = '';
      this.used = false;
    }
  }

}
```

but fails on serve as

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
|
>   id:number;
```

what is the way to have a typed class, is any 3rd party npm ?

**[edit]**

found on Vue [website](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)
Create a new project, then choose the "Manually select features" option

> vue create my-project-name

[image]

testing to a new project. A **package.json** of **vue2** with **typescript** support, hmm [vue-property-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator)

```js
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `webpack`; beyond changing the extension, you'll need to use [`ts-loader`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) to teach Webpack to work with Typescript files. That's the "additional loader" your error message refers to. If you'd like confirmation or additional help, please post your `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: @JeffBowman - hmm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator, using vue25, found out now that vueCLI3 that comes with vue25, but no idea howto for the moment.. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: What you posted is Eslint error, it's not related to the way the app is build. Eslint needs to be configured to support TS.

Comment: `vue-cli` is ["built on top of webpack"](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/). You can tweak the way it works through [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration); do you have one of those you can post?

Comment: @JeffBowman - too much dependencies to have a typed class... The plan is dropped. :( thanks for your comments.